# How to update a row in a field one at a time on php?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem on updating the status field on `tblitemlist`. I wanted to display all status = 'PENDING' and when it's done, what I want to do is update its status to finished with just clicking a button. I wanted it one by one and not clicking a button and update everything at the same time. Please help me

here's what i did:

```
$query_update = mysql_query("UPDATE tblitemlist SET status = 'FINISHED'") or die(mysql_error());
```

I tried this one. There's no error but when I checked my database, the status is not changing.

`$id=$_GET['id'];`

```
    $query_update = mysql_query("UPDATE tblitemlist SET status = 'FINISHED' WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Gonna show my codes..

**inner.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

include("../connection/connection.php");
//
if(!isset($_SESSION['u']))
{ 
header("location../resto/index.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT tblcustomer.fname, tblitemlist.item, tblitemlist.category, tblitemlist.date_ordered FROM tblitemlist INNER JOIN tblcustomer ON tblcustomer.cust_id=tblitemlist.cust_id WHERE tblitemlist.status='PENDING' ORDER BY tblcustomer.cust_id" ) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table width='900' border='1' align='center'>";
echo "<tr>";
//echo "<td>Code</td>";
echo "<td align='center' style='font-size:20px;'>Name</td>";
echo "<td align='center' style='font-size:20px;'>Item</td>";
echo "<td align='center' style='font-size:20px;'>Category</td>";
echo "<td align='center' style='font-size:20px;'>Date</td>";
echo "<td align='center' style='font-size:20px;'>Status</td>";

echo "<tr>";

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    //echo "<td>" .$row['code'];
    echo "<td>" .$row['fname'];
    echo "<td>" .$row['item'];
    echo "<td>" .$row['category'];
    echo "<td>" .$row['date_ordered'];



?>

<td><a href="update.php?>$id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">DONE</a></td>
<?php
echo "<tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
}
?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**update.php**

```
<?php error_reporting(0); ?>  

<?php 

include ("../connection/connection.php");  
$id=$_GET['id'];

        $query_update = mysql_query("UPDATE tblitemlist SET status='FINISHED' WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());

        if($query_update){
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("COOKED");
            window.location="index.php";
            </script>';
        }
        else{
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("UNSUCCESSFULL");
            window.location="index.php";
            </script>';
        }





?>
```

Comment: Looks good, is it giving error

Comment: submit the id from which the button was clicked and use it in the where clause, so that you just update the single row

Comment: not at all. The only problem is that its updating everything. What I wanted is to update a single row @Rajesh

Comment: This `error_reporting(0);` suppresses errors. Use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` then display them with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` - Is `session_start();` loaded also, since you are using sessions.

Comment: This `update.php?>$id=<?php echo $row['id']` that doesn't look right. It should be something like `update.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>`

Comment: Not getting errors but nothing happened to my database.. not updating. @Fred-ii-

Comment: You'll need to start using `var_dump();` on your variables then, and look at your HTML source to determine what's being passed or not. I.e. `var_dump($id);` and do so for other variables.

Comment: You also have `echo "<tr>";` just above `echo "</table>";` that should be `echo "</tr>";` - You're also not closing your `<td>` tags for `echo "<td>" .$row['fname'];` - such as `echo "<td>" .$row['fname'] . "</td>";` and others.

Comment: See these on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/25957771/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/25725860/ those will give you examples/pointers on doing updates. You will need a form to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add WHERE statement to specify which table item has to be updated. First you have to provide the query with the ID. For example, each button would post the 'id_to_update' through a form.

```
$query_update = mysql_query("UPDATE tblitemlist SET status = 'FINISHED' WHERE id = ".$_POST['id_to_update']) or die(mysql_error());
```

Is that what you want ?

Comment: Tried this one but it gives me error. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Kim Describe "error". The person who answered needs to know what the exact error message is.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 

Thanks for reminding me. I'm new here by the way! *Peace* :) @Fred-ii-

Comment: You have a syntax error while creating your table :
`<td><a href="update.php?>$id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">DONE</a></td>`
Replace with :
`<td><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">DONE</a></td>`

Comment: This error prevented your script to pass the id in the URL, thus the MySQL request tried to set id to nothing, which is incorrect.